# webapi cors error in HttpPost method in webapi

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WebAPI server and javascript client.
I have below code in webapi that does work

```
    [EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("Controller/ConditionFiles")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetConditionFiles()
        {
            var files = await Task.Run(() => new DirectoryInfo(workingFolder).GetFiles().Select(o => o.Name.Replace(".csv","")).ToArray());
            return Ok(files);

        }
```

However below code (HttpPost) doesn't work

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:8080", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
        [Route("Controller/MultiComplexity")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetMultiComplexity()
        {
            var vlFileNamesList=new List<string>();
            var vlFileContents=new List<string>();
            var result = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
            var processFile = result.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var length = Convert.ToInt32(result.Contents[1].ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            var closeVias = result.Contents[2].ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            int i=3;
            for(i=3;i<length+3;i++)
            {
                vlFileNamesList.Add(result.Contents[i].ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }
            for(;i<2*length+3;i++)
            {
                vlFileContents.Add(result.Contents[i].ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
            }

            var closeViasBool = closeVias == "true";
            if (processFile != "")
            {
                var process = File.ReadAllText(workingFolder + processFile + ".csv");
                var vlFileAnalyzer = new MultiVLFiles.MultiVLFiles_class();
                //return Ok(new ABC() { a = vlFileContents.ToArray(), b = vlFileNamesList , c=process});
                bool isError=false;
                var complexity = await Task.Run(() => vlFileAnalyzer.getFinalComplexity(vlFileContents.ToArray(), vlFileNamesList, process, closeViasBool, "NA", "NA", isError));
                return Ok(complexity);
            }
            return Ok("No Process was selected");
        }
```

and returns below error
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.httpost

My web.config has below section

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:8080" />
      </customHeaders>
```

Also, I installed cors (from nuget) and have below lines in WebApiConfig.cs file-

```
    config.EnableCors();
```

What can be the issue? how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the latest version of dot net core with web api.

First up, I would strongly recommend that you start from scratch, because, you have done a lot of things which might clash with the correct steps provided below.

Adding CORS (in the latest version) is simple and happens in two steps.

Step 1 - ConfigureServices

```
        //lets add some CORS stuff 
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => {
                builder.WithOrigins(tempConfigHelperStuff.AddCorsOrigin1LocalHost,
                                    tempConfigHelperStuff.AddCorsOrigin2ProductionSite,
                                    tempConfigHelperStuff.AddCorsOrigin3DevOrTestOrSomethingElseSite);
                builder.AllowAnyMethod();
                builder.AllowAnyHeader();
                builder.AllowCredentials();
            });
        });
```

Note : WithOrigins(tempConfigHelperStuff.AddCorsOrigin1LocalHost, here, "tempConfigHelperStuff.AddCorsOrigin1LocalHost" is just some string like "www.something.com" or "localhost:PORTNUMBER" where you are running your web app or something.
Step 2 - Configure

```
        app.UseCors();
```

Finally, in my experience, exactly where you put these lines of code, also matters. I have a working demo server code with this code, fully working

https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/RandomStuffGenerator/blob/master/RandomStuffGeneratorPrivate/RandomStuffGeneratorPrivate/Startup.cs